# no pg_hba.conf entry for host

Tags: postgresql

I get following error when I try to connect using DBI

```
DBI connect('database=chaosLRdb;host=192.168.0.1;port=5433','postgres',...) 
failed: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.168.0.1", user "postgres", database "chaosLRdb", SSL off
```

Here is my pg_hba.conf file:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all         all                               md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               md5

host    all         postgres    127.0.0.1/32          trust

host    all        postgres     192.168.0.1/32        trust

host    all        all         192.168.0.1/32        trust

host    all        all         192.168.0.1/128        trust

host    all        all         192.168.0.1/32        md5

host    chaosLRdb    postgres         192.168.0.1/32      md5
local    all        all         192.168.0.1/32        trust
```

My perl code is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl-w
use DBI;
use FileHandle;

print "Start connecting to the DB...\n";

@ary = DBI->available_drivers(true);
%drivers = DBI->installed_drivers();
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:PgPP:database=chaosLRdb;host=192.168.0.1;port=5433", "postgres", "chaos123");
```

May I know what i miss here?

Answer (score 68):

If you can change this line:

```
host    all        all         192.168.0.1/32        md5
```

With this:

```
host    all        all         all                   md5
```

You can see if this solves the problem.

But another consideration is your postgresql port(5432) is very open to password attacks with hackers (maybe they can brute force the password). You can change your postgresql port 5432 to '33333' or another value, so they can't know this configuration.

Comment: I tried to do it like "host    all        all         *                   md5" . But it didn't worked. But I got succeeded in your way. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This solution made me realize that I did not understand the fourth parameter at all, thank you!

Answer (score 41):

In your pg_hba.conf file, I see some incorrect and confusing lines:

```
# fine, this allows all dbs, all users, to be trusted from 192.168.0.1/32
# not recommend because of the lax permissions
host    all        all         192.168.0.1/32        trust

# wrong, /128 is an invalid netmask for ipv4, this line should be removed
host    all        all         192.168.0.1/128       trust

# this conflicts with the first line
# it says that that the password should be md5 and not plaintext
# I think the first line should be removed
host    all        all         192.168.0.1/32        md5

# this is fine except is it unnecessary because of the previous line
# which allows any user and any database to connect with md5 password
host    chaosLRdb  postgres    192.168.0.1/32        md5

# wrong, on local lines, an IP cannot be specified
# remove the 4th column
local   all        all         192.168.0.1/32        trust
```

I suspect that if you md5'd the password, this might work if you trim the lines.  To get the md5 you can use perl or the following shell script:

```
 echo -n 'chaos123' | md5sum
 > d6766c33ba6cf0bb249b37151b068f10  -
```

So then your connect line would like something like:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:PgPP:database=chaosLRdb;host=192.168.0.1;port=5433",
    "chaosuser", "d6766c33ba6cf0bb249b37151b068f10");
```

For more information, here's the [documentation of postgres 8.X's pg_hba.conf file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/client-authentication.html).

Comment: Yeah, it probably refused to load the pg_hba.conf file because of the errors.

Answer (score 11):

If you are getting this error using node and pg module you can set ssl to not reject unauthorized access like this

```
const pool = new Pool({
    connectionString: "your connection string",
    ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
})
```

Answer (score 8):

Your postgres server configuration seems correct

`host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          md5
host    all         all         192.168.0.1/32        trust`

That should grant access from the client to the postgres server. So that leads me to believe the username / password is whats failing.

Test this by creating a specific user for that database

`createuser -a -d -W -U postgres chaosuser`

Then adjust your perl script to use the newly created user

`my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:PgPP:database=chaosLRdb;host=192.168.0.1;port=5433", "chaosuser", "chaos123");`

Comment: The fact that he got an error about a missing pg_hba.conf line means that it hasn't gotten to checking the password yet.

Answer (score 7):

Add the following in line in pg_hba.conf

hostnossl    all          all            0.0.0.0/0  trust

And then restart the Service.

Comment: Isn't this super insecure?

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same issue. My db was on cloud

Error:

> ERROR: no pg_hba.conf entry for host ".......", user ".........", database "....", SSL off

I add this configuration to resolve this,

```
    "dialect": "postgres",
    "dialectOptions": {
        "ssl": {
            "require": true,
            "rejectUnauthorized": false
        }
    }
```

SSL parameter is the key telling DB to always use SSL for making connections.

Comment: There is no param `dialectOptions.ssl.require` in pg package, see source file: node_modules\pg\lib\connection-parameters.js, so it is useless.

Answer (score 6):

To resolve this problem, you can try this.

first, you have found out your pg_hba.conf by:

cd /etc/postgresql/9.5/main from your root directory

and open file using

```
sudo nano pg_hba.conf
```

then add this line:

```
local   all         all                               md5
```

to your pg_hba.conf and then restart by using the command:

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Comment: Hello 'local' is relevant for unix socket connections. Why do you think it should help with the network problem? (I have this line in my pg_hba.conf, too, and have the same problem, too, plus my postgresql server does not listen on unix socket.)

Answer (score 3):

To resolved this problem, you can try this.

first you have find out your pg_hba.conf and write :

```
local all all md5
```

after that restart pg server:

```
postgresql restart
```

or

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

Answer (score 3):

**Use SSL in the connection**. This solves it instantly

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting an error like the one below:

```
OperationalError: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "your ipv6",
                  user "username", database "postgres", SSL off
```

then add an entry like the following, with your mac address.

```
host   all    all       [your ipv6]/128         md5
```

Comment: My problem was related to the IPV6 address, so, adding specifically my IPV6 address solved the problem. Thanks Shiddu

Answer (score 2):

while making the connection include ssl prop in configugration like this:

```
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who have the similar problem trying to connect to local db and trying like
`con = psycopg2.connect(database="my_db", user="my_name", password="admin")`, try to pass the additional parameter, so the following saved me a day:
`con = psycopg2.connect(database="my_db", user="my_name", password="admin", host="localhost")`

Comment: Using 'local' saved my day too!  The full host name works remotely but it did not work locally.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are getting this error in DBeaver the solution was found [here](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/1219) at line:

*@lcustodio on the SSL page, set SSL mode: require and either leave the SSL Factory blank or use the org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory*

Under Network -> SSL tab I checked the Use SLL checkbox and set Advance -> SSL Mode = require and it now works.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Docker container to run postgres. I faced this issue and to resolve this, I used `POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust` env variable at the time of  starting container.

Here is an example command
`docker run --name postgres --net appnet -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -p 5432:5432  -e POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust  -d postgres`

If you want to connect postgres container to any other application which is running inside a docker container, it is best to run both the containers in same network. In this case, I have created a network ***appnet*** using `docker network create` command, used it to create my application container and postgres container.

Comment: this, this one works in Kubernetes.

Answer (score 1):

On my server that was running postgresql, I edited the file */etc/postgresql/11/main/pg_hba.conf* and added the following line:

```
host    all             all             10.2.3.100/32            md5
```

I then restarted the postgresql server using the command **service postgresql restart** to pick up this change. This allowed pgAdmin to connect to my postgresql server. pgAdmin was running on my desktop computer (the client) which has IP address 10.2.3.100. The postgresql server was running on a server (the server) with IP address 10.2.3.50

Answer (score 0):

also check the PGHOST variable:

> ECHO $PGHOST

to see if it matches the local machine name

Answer (score 0):

BTW, in my case it was that I needed to specify the user/pwd in the url, not as independent properties, they were ignored and my OS user was used to connect

My config is in a WebSphere 8.5.5 server.xml file

```
<dataSource 
    jndiName="jdbc/tableauPostgreSQL" 
    type="javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource">
    <jdbcDriver 
        javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource="org.postgresql.ds.PGConnectionPoolDataSource" 
        javax.sql.DataSource="org.postgresql.ds.PGPoolingDataSource" 
        libraryRef="PostgreSqlJdbcLib"/>
    <properties 
        url="jdbc:postgresql://server:port/mydb?user=fred&amp;password=secret"/>
</dataSource>
```

This would not work and was getting the error:

```
<properties 
    user="fred"
    password="secret"
    url="jdbc:postgresql://server:port/mydb"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following line in /etc/postgresql/14/main/pg_hba.conf file

#IPv4 local connections:

host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256

host    all             all             all                     md5

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue in Azure Data Factory while connecting to Azure Database  for PostgreSQL.

28000: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "", user "", database "postgres", **SSL off**

Here the issue was due to PostgreSQL database has ssl_min_protocol_version set to TLSV1.2 expecting a encrypted connection and the client connection was not using any encryption.

I've resolved the issue by setting the property "Encryption method" to SSL

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In one project I was facing this issue and after all changes like in config the issue was still same.
Then the steps that I followed:
I restart the PgSQL from WHM `Home / Restart Services / SQL Server (PgSQL)`

```
Create the new db

Create new user

Assign user to db
```

that was missing in earlier "I created new because it was live server and uploading files on that server for the first time."

```
Add new db name and password in env
```

Import the DB from terminal `psql -U {_new_user} -d {new_db} -f {db.sql}`

Now it's done and run the application
If it's still not working after env change then **try with cache clear**

Answer (score 0):

In NodeJS using [postgres-pool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postgres-pool#aws-rds-specific-tls-settings-for-connections) package there is one option specifically for the AWS RDS connections.

```js
const pgPool = new Pool({
  connectionString: connectionString,
  ssl: 'aws-rds' // AWS RDS specific TLS settings for connections
});
```

Below refer this package interface comment for your ready reference.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue then realized it was something silly. Using Java Spring Boot, my connection url looked something like:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://database:5432/database_dev?sslmode=disable
```

This is fine for dev environments, but the ***?sslmode=disable*** needs to be remove for prod environments:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://database:5432/database_prod
```

After that, it worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

Reporting my experience where users are facing the error message:

```
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "my.host", user "my_user", database "myDB", SSL off
```

Enabling SSL (DBeaver connecting to Redshift) as per:

[image]

helped realising that their credentials have been updated by having the easier error message:

```
FATAL: password authentication failed for user "my_user"
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting thing, but this is fact.

```
--package.json---
dependencies:
   "pg": "^8.11.3",
   "sequelize": "^4.44.4"
}
```

This is test app with dialectOptions - connection is alive.

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  database: "my_database",
  host: "myhost",
  port: 5432,
  username: "myusername",
  password: "myPass",
  dialect: "postgres",
  dialectOptions: {
    ssl: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    },
  },
});

sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("******************we are good - connection is alive****************");
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.error("Troubles. Error", e);
  });
```

If `dialectOptions` is empty, no `ssl` property, app fails with error:

Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "myhost", user "myusername", database "my_database", no encryption

What is interesting, if `dialectOptions: {ssl:{}}` (ssl is empty object, which means all flags set to false) it works too - connection is alive.

Not sure if it is a defect of pg@8 or something else.

Answer (score -1):

Add the following in line in pg_hba.conf

hostnossl all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust

restart the server

Answer (score -2):

Verify the postgres connection hostname/address in pgadmin and use the same in your connection parameter.

DBI connect('database=chaosLRdb;host=**"keep what is mentioned"** ;port=5433','postgres',...)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The user never mentions it can access the database using pgAdmin.