# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to connect to PostgreSQL database which is in remote location using Spring JDBC template. I am getting

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "139.126.243.71", user "guest", database "masterdb", SSL off error

I don't have access to pg_hba.conf file of the remote location.

This is the configuration I gave in my spring servlet.xml

```xml
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://100.64.35.52":5432/masterdb"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="root"/>
</bean>
```

Can we solve the issue by giving any properties?

Comment: At a guess, SSL is probably required. Try adding `?ssl=true` to the JDBC URI.

Comment: I tried by adding ?ssl=true to the JDBC URI but it still shows the same error.  org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "139.126.243.71", user "guest", database "masterdb", SSL on

Comment: If pg_hba.conf prevents connection to that database from your IP, then there is nothing you can do other than ask the admin to change pg_hba.conf Did you try to connect with simple psql program?

Comment: what about mac with same issue

Answer (score 66):

It seems that DB server does not allow SSL off connection, You will have to enable it. Change URL from `jdbc:postgresql://100.64.35.52":5432/masterdb` to  `jdbc:postgresql://100.64.35.52":5432/masterdb?sslmode=require`

Check mode details about ssl mode at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-ssl.html

Comment: Fixed it for connection to a heroku postgres instance.

Comment: Works like a charm @Amit! Fixed for connection to heroku postgres!

Comment: Fixed my connection problem when trying to connect to a vendor remote box using the SQuirreL client and I could NOT make changes on their DB server configuration.  Thanks for the post even though it was almost 1 year old.  Appreciate the help!!

Comment: Same here, fixed for heroku postgres connection.

Comment: Fixed my problem with a connection to an AWS RDB.   Thank you!

Comment: With driver 9.4 just add sslmode=require solved my problems

Comment: Fised heroku postgres connection from local

Comment: getting error `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server does not support SSL.` when add in the `?sslmode=require`, any alternative way I can do?

Answer (score 39):

You must apply below changes to connect:

Navigate to the the following location `C:\Program Files (maybe x86)\PostgreSQL\(your version)\data`

**`postgresql.conf`** file:

check the  `listen_addresses` be = `*` ( by default its localhost in some postgres versions) if it isn't you must change it to `*`. It's used to listen on all interfaces.

**`pg_hba.conf`** file:

add a new row :

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

( use of above row is better)
or

```
host guest masterdb 139.126.243.71 md5
```

And finally it's very important that the ssl mode is to be on. For this add below command in the end of your url:

```
?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```

In Terms of Bean as

```xml
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://100.64.35.52":5432/masterdb?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="root"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: I didn't change pg_hba.conf file at all. Just add ?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory works for me.

Comment: Just changed the pg_hba.conf and restarted postgresql.
It worked for me.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Worked like a charm for me! ^_^

Comment: Hey, where shall I add the SSL command. I do not see any xml file for my configs. Is there any way I can edit it in pg_hba.conf?

Comment: Azure Postgres SQL (flexible). 
`?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory`
This one worked for me. Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 6):

**Error explanation**

The file `pg_hba.conf` (host-based authentication configuration file) is used to control the client authentication. This file is located in the database cluster's data directory.

The error `java.sql.SQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "<your-host-ip>", user "<postgres-user>", database "<db-name>", SSL off` means that Postgres accepts SSL connections but your are trying to connect without SSL.

**Secured connection**

If a certificate is requested from the client during SSL connection startup, it means that the DBA has set the `clientcert` parameter in `pg_hba.conf`. Note that if `clientcert` is not specified (or set to 0), the server will NOT insist that a client certificate be presented.

**Check if database server is using SSL**

Before trying to access your SSL enabled server from Java, make sure that you can get to it via `psql`.

If you want to connect with a given user at a given port:

```
$ psql -h <server-ip> -p <server-port> -d <db-name> -U <user>
```

Or if you want to connect at the default port with your current user:

```
$ psql -h <server-ip>
```

You should see an such output if you have established a SSL connection:

```
$ psql -h <server-ip> -d <db-name> -U <user>
psql (11.2, Server 9.6.5)

SSL connection (cipher: DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits: 256)
```

Note that the last line contains 'SSL connection'.

**JDBC connection parameters**

- `ssl` must be set if the server required a secured connection. Note that both `ssl=true` or `ssl` work but `ssl=true` is recommended for the coming future release of Postgres.
- `sslfactory` provides the class name to use as the SSLSocketFactory when establishing a SSL connection.

The JDBC driver provdies an option to establish a SSL connection without doing any validation (but it's risky!).

A non-validating connection is established via a custom `SSLSocketFactory` class that is provided with the driver. Setting the connection URL parameter `sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory` will turn off all SSL validation.

This was my case and why I also got the same error you had. So, to establish the connection I have:

```
jdbc:postgresql://<ip-address>:<port>/<db-name>?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```

**References**

- [Postgres JDBC SSL](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/ssl.html)
- [Postgres JDBC NonValidating](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/94/ssl-client.html#nonvalidating)
- [Postgres SSL-TCP](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/ssl-tcp.html)

Answer (score 5):

**Combined settings**

I tried the suggestions given by @craig-ringer

```
jdbc:postgresql://100.64.35.52":5432/masterdb?ssl=true
```

and given by @amit

```
jdbc:postgresql://100.64.35.52":5432/masterdb?sslmode=require
```

neither worked. But when I combined them to:

```
jdbc:postgresql://100.64.35.52":5432/masterdb?ssl=true&sslmode=require
```

It worked.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406025/no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host/49036072#49036072), basically had to put user/pwd in url property

```
url="jdbc:postgresql://server:port/mydb?user=fred&amp;password=secret"
```

Comment: I had the same issue, although I was supplying username/password another way, they were wrong!  I guess PostgreSQL thinks 'user auth didn't work, let's try host-based auth', and then forgets to mention the first condition when complaining that the latter one didn't work. :-\

Answer (score 0):

You must have root access edit `pg_hba.conf`.

- goto **root** user
- edit `/var/lib/pgsql/12/data/pg_hba.conf`

host    all             all             139.126.243.71/32         trust

1. Restart Postgres [`service postgresql-12.service restart`].