# I have an error when migrating manager.py on Hostmidia

Tags: django, postgresql

> File "/home/interlog/virtualenv/sistema_interlogrs/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 275, in get_new_connection
> connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
> File "/home/interlog/virtualenv/sistema_interlogrs/3.9/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/**init**.py", line 122, in connect
> conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
> django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "::1", user "interlog_user", database "interlog_site", SSL off

Comment: Does this answer your question? [no pg\_hba.conf entry for host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406025/no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host)