Can't connect postgresql docker to dbeaver
I create a container posgresql with this command: docker run --name posgre_db  -e POSTGRES_USER="user" -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD="password" -p 5432:5432 -d postgres:latest
when i try to create a connection with DBeaver i get a error:

I can go into the container
λ docker exec -it posgre_db psql -U user -d postgres
psql (16.4 (Debian 16.4-1.pgdg120+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#

In DBeaver


I edit connection, i put in host: 192.168.1.15, and i get this error:
FATAL: No entry in pg_hba.conf for host 192.168.1.15, user user,
'postgres' database, no encryption
FATAL: No entry in pg_hba.conf for host 192.168.1.15, user user,
'postgres' database, no encryption


-U postgreSQL is using username postgreSQL, under DBeaver you are trying to use another username.

You appear to be running multiple database containers. Are you sure that posgre_db is actually running. If you used -p 5432:5432 for both then one of them will have failed to start up as you can only expose the port 5432 on your host machine once. Try starting your container again with -p 6000:5432 and use port 6000 to connect from dbeaver.

Hello, Excusez me, as I had the connection error I thought that there was a problem with the use of capital letters in the user name, so I recreated another instance with the names in lower case, but I still got the same problem and i delete the first instance

see: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83984/connect-to-postgresql-server-fatal-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host and/or  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406025/no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host
